# Laravel real time notification

Tags: laravel

I have created an application In laravel. When one user create a job it must be notified by the other user. For notification I used laravel notification. But I need to refresh the page to get notification. How can I get the notification in real time.

Comment: For real time notification you need to learn about `Node.js`

Comment: Or more easily achieved using [events, listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events) and [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new comment notify flow, FYI.

[image]

#### Laravel

User Model

```php
namespace App\Models\Sys;

use App\Models\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'user';
    
    public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {
        return 'user.' . $this->id;
    }
}
```

Run the listener

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=1
```

#### NodeJS

Install packages

```
npm i laravel-echo laravel-echo-server pm2 socket.io-client
```

Start laravel echo server

```
node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js  start
```

Import echo in `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + (process.env.MIX_APP_ENV === 'local' ? ':6001' : ''),
    auth: {
        headers: {}
    },
});
```

Receive notification in page

```
<script>
    Echo.private('user.' + uid)
        .notification((e) => {
            // do something
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Would you please clarify your answer by adding more info?

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways for doing that, from laravel you can use Laravel Broadcasting, click [here!](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)

In there you can find tutorial to setup your server (laravel) and your frontend

Answer (score 0):

The newest laravel version comes with [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting), this is a tool to get exactly what you want.

You could use your laravel application to broadcast events.
You can then define the channels on which you want to broadcast these events.

Then you need to [receive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts) these broadcasts on your front-end.

This setup also needs a [driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) to be used, this could be pusher, redis, or many others.